# What am I missing? API Python issues

Tags: python, google-blogger-api

I am trying to get a blog by ID from Blogger.

Here's what Blogger API docs say I should add:

```
get(blogId=*, x__xgafv=None, maxPosts=None, view=None)
```

Gets a blog by id.

Args:

- blogId: string, A parameter (required)
- x__xgafv: string, V1 error format.
  Allowed values

  - 1 - v1 error format
  - 2 - v2 error format
- maxPosts: integer, A parameter
- view: string, A parameter

I've taken out the sensitive information (like the API Key):

```
url = 'blogger's url and api key'
PARAMS = {blogID = '######'}

blogs = requests.get(url, PARAMS)

print(blogs)
```

> <Response [403]>

Is this an issue with authentication, or am I screwing something up?

I can do a get request on the url + api key and it returns <Response [200]>, so I'm certain I'm communicating with the correct server. It's just that I thought the API key would be enough to get back some basic blog post information.

I've looked at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

and I'm clueless as to what I'm missing...these are arguments, right? That link only mentions parameters, and I can't figure out the syntax I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be conflating `blogUserInfos.get` and `requests.get`, which are entirely different methods in entirely different modules.

I don't know anything about Blogger or the Blogger API - I've never used it or even know what it is, but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingABlog) indicates that you can make a simple HTTP GET request to the desired blog (by ID), and include your API key in the query string of the request URL. You would make this request using `requests.get`. The URL from the documentation looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

Where `2399953` is the blog ID, and `YOUR-API-KEY` is your API key. The response will be JSON, I'm guessing.

Comment: Okay, makes sense...what is this referring to then? https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/blogger/v3/python/latest/blogger_v3.blogUserInfos.html